# matrix math using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` that I'd like to perform matrix multiplication with.  Can pandas do that?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 5))
```

I don't want to have to do this:

```
df.values.dot(df.values)
```

Comment: do you mean `df.mul(df)`? or `np.dot(df,df)`?

Comment: have you consider transform `df` to matrix? `m = np.mat(df)`

Comment: @EdChum I meant `np.dot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas `DataFrame`'s also have a [`dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) method.

Just do this:

```
df.dot(df)
```

Comment: I bet `df.dot` ends up calling `np.dot` on the values.  What's its code say?